# Failing importing module to Slurm

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, slurm

I am a beginner and I am starting using a local cluster that works with Slurm.
I am able to execute some python codes with the usual modules (numpy, scipy, etc..) but as I try to run a script that includes my own library: myownlib.py, the following message is displayed:

> No module named myownlib

I sought a lot for the solution, probably looking in the wrong direction. Hereby what I tried to fix this:

- I created an environment file, with conda;
- I wrote the following test.sh

(That led to the error mentioned before)

```
#!/bin/bash  
module purge
source myownlib-devel #This is the name I gave into the environment file)
/usr/bin/python ~/filexample.py
```

Any suggestions?
(Thank you in advance...)

Comment: Just to be clear. Before the whole slurm issue, were you able to load the module locally ? Meaning without a slurm submission ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most probable cause could be a difference in Python version between the login node where you created the environment and the compute nodes. If you loaded a specific Python module with `module load` for creating the virtual env, you should load the same module in the submission script. The default Python version for the login node could be Python 3 while the default version for the compute nodes could be Python 2, depending on the Linux distribution and list of modules loaded.

Comment: This is an actually useful advise that is not usually pointed out or emphasized in documentations. I've fallen for this trap a few times already. Now I basically reload all needed environment first before doing something.